# SlickGrid multi row select

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have been looking for built in multi-row select. I see that I could override the selection method but I was really hoping that it was built in to the tool.

I add row selection with the RowSelectionModel.

```
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());
```

Should I be using something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like by default the multi-row select is activated. After looking into the live elements I saw that the selected row would be given a selected css class, but this css class was not applying any sort of color to the row. I added some css for that class and the other rows began to get highlighted.